# How to write an ingest pipeline for elastic search to load a csv file as nested JSONs?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, kibana, data-ingestion

I have a csv file that has the following format:

| company_id | year | sales | buys | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2020 | 230 | 112 | europe |
| 3 | 2019 | 234 | 231 | europe |
| 2 | 2020 | 443 | 351 | usa |
| 2 | 2019 | 224 | 256 | usa |

and when I import it to elastic search I end up having one entry for each line.
However, I would like to import it in the format below:

```
[
{"company_id" : 3, 
    "location" : "europe", 
    "2020" : {"sales" : 230, "buys" : 112}, 
    "2019" : {"sales" : 234, "buys" : 231}
  }, 
{"company_id" : 2, 
    "location" : "usa", 
    "2020" : {"sales" : 443, "buys" : 351},
    "2019" : {"sales" : 224, "buys" : 256}
  } 
]
```

Is there a way to write the ingest pipeline (processor) in order to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your precious answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the ingest pipeline level you'll only be able to handle one document (i.e. one row) at a time, so in order to aggregate the way you want, you need to do it at the Logstash level using the [`aggregate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/plugins-filters-aggregate.html).

if your rows are correctly sorted by location, you can use the [following example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example4) from the official documentation.

One word of caution, though: if you add `year` as a field, your mapping will keep growing as years go by and you potentially risk [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/mapping-settings-limit.html).